# Subversion ignore classes directory after its been added (and linked to src directory)

Tags: svn

I've got an existing JAVA subversion repository with the classes directory already added. 
For some reason the classes directory is pointing to the source directory in the repository, since everytime we try ignore or delete the classes directory, it applies the same change to the source directory. 
I'm using TortoiseSVN on Windows Vista.

How do I ignore the directory and kill the link?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your working copy is mixed up. Try deleting it and re-checking it out. You can check where each directory in the repository is checked out to by looking at the properties (in your WC) that should show you the repository url.

If that's not the case, do you have a junction set on your local drive that is associating the 2 directories together?